# Geb - perform Ctrl + P

Tags: grails, selenium, geb

is it possible to perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> click with Geb? I tried it like this, but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
interact {
            keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
            sendKeys("P")
            keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send non-character key presses using WebDriver's `Key.chord()` method:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

$("input", name: "firstName") << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "P")
```

See [this section of the manual](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#non_characters_eg_delete_key) for more information.

Comment: I read this before. The problem with this code is I need an element which to perform key presses. But in my app, I need to perform "CTRL + P" (same shortcut for printing), without focusing on any elements. I tried this: $() << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "P"), but it throws an error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: How is the key press handled in your app? Is the event handler being bound to the body of the document? If it is then try `$('body') << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "P")`.

Comment: @erdi, how could you use something similar to open the Print Preview page, using the Chrome driver? I don't believe it's really possible, as it's a browser shortcut (Ctrl+P). Any tips on how can this be achieved? The goal is get to the print view, so I can extract the link to the generated PDF (https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=19), and download it.

Comment: I'm able to open the Print View using java.awt.Robot, and sending the keys from there, but then I'm unable to access any HTML inside the Print View page, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can use interact..

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
interact {
keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
keyDown(Keys.P)
}
```